# In "Getting Started with Apex Triggers," "Adding Related Records" are the types wrong?

Tags: data-types, trailhead

Looking at their code, it seems to be the type should be `Map<Id, List<Id>>` or `Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>` but they have `Map<Id, Account>`.  When I tried to run the code in a different context (a static method in a class) it seems to think the type should be `List<Account>`.

I'm thoroughly screwed up.  What's going on?

Here's their writeup:  https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/force_com_dev_beginner/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro

```
// This is from Getting Started With Apex Triggers, Adding Related Records.
// To me, it seems like the types are screwed up.
public class SomeClass {
    public static void doQuery() {
        // Map<Id, Account> aMap;
        // Illegal assignment from List<Account> to Map<Id,Account>
        // when we tried to assign to aMap.
        // 
        // Map<Id, List<Id> > aMap;
        // Illegal assignment from List<Account> to Map<Id,List<Id>>
        // 
        // Map<Id, List<Opportunity> > aMap;
        // Map<Id, Opportunity> aMap;
        List<Account> aMap;  // Note, not really a map.
        // aMap = [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account];
        // This ran.  Gave me a long list of accounts.  And they are accounts, too.  Not opportunities.
        aMap = [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account where id = '0013600000PRUaLAAX'];
        // Here's a line from the log from running this.
        // 09:17:43:020 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [14]|aMap|{"s":1,"v":[
        //    {
        //       "s":2,"v":{"Id":"0013600000PRUaLAAX","Opportunities":[
        //          {"s":3,"v":{"AccountId":"0013600000PRUaLAAX","Id":"00636000008jHLLAA2"}},
        //          {"s":4,"v":{"AccountId":"0013600000PRUaLAAX","Id":"00636000008jHKzAAM"}},
        //          {"s":5,"v":{"AccountId":"0013600000PRUaLAAX","Id":"00636000008jHL6AAM"}},
        //          {"s":6,"v":{"AccountId":"0013600000PRUaLAAX","Id":"00636000008jHL7AAM"}}
        //       ]}
        //    }
        // ]}|0x2f6750cf
        // So, what does this mean?
        System.debug(aMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original

```
Map<ID,Account>
```

is correct. The query is a list of Accounts containing its child opportunities.

The query returns a list but there is a shortcut to convert it to a map directly when you perform the query

```
aMap = New Map<ID,Account>([SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account where id = '0013600000PRUaLAAX']);
```

remove `List<Account> aMap;  // Note, not really a map.`

Comment: I totally missed the fact that they did a cast.  I need to carefully go through queries, and make sure I understand them in detail.

Comment: @user2171796 - It is not really a cast so I removed that from the answer. It instantiates the map with the query as the parameter

Comment: I think they used the 3rd constructor: Map<ID,sObject>(recordList)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm
thanks for the pointer, was a bit confused with that as well

Answer (score 1):

They have simply opted for the least verbose option. Sure you can convert it to `Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>`, but that takes several more lines of code. You can still get the `List<Opportunity>` for any Id in the `keySet`.

```
List<Opportunity> children = acctsWithOpps.get(accountId).Opportunities;
```

Whereas converting it is simply more verbose. Might as well use a one-liner.

```
Map<Id, List<Opportunity>> children = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();
for (Account parent : [/*query*/])
{
    children.put(parent.Id, parent.Opportunities);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you've posted for the single record query is shorthand for all opportunities related to that account. You get the same if you query it as a map.

```
Map<Id,Account> acctsWithOpps = new Map<Id,Account>(
    [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New]);
```

You can pull this out from the query to work with it by doing something like the following:

```
list<Account>Accts = new list<Account>();
list<Opportunity>Opps = new list<Opportunity>();

For(Id aId:acctsWithOpps.keyset())
{
    account a = acctsWithOpps.get(aId); // each account in map
     Accts.add(a); // add each account to a list

    list<Opportunities> aOpps = a.Opportunities; // each accts rel opp is a list    

        For(Opportuny o: aOpps){
            Opps.add(o); // add related opps to list of opportunities
            // you can also put these in a map to accountId or account
            // mapname.put(o.Id,aId);         
        }    
}
```